# jsp(springMVC) store data in session or request to retrieve between same page requests

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, session

I have a JSP page, lets say **events_index.jsp** that gets all the events in the system. i am using spring MVC pagedListHolder to implement pagination. do i need to store the data source in request or session. if i store it in session, new events created will not come into list unless i close the browser before creating a new event. If i store in request it fetches entire data from database every time as it cannot find data in next request object. i need data to retain only between **events_index.jsp** requests only but not entire session.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question you need to show latest data everytime you paginate?
Even you are paginating in same page for every next or prev , there is a http request goes to server and as per pageSize and offset setting server returns data.
so this happens for every **request** and you will get latest data.

If you store paging data in session and serve the subsequent request from session you may not have latest state of data.

So I suggest use request to show latest data [may hit performance]
use session to show data[may not show latest data]